# Can I avoid cluttering my class with repetitive XmlElement attributes even though the root node is in a different namespace than its children?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am retrieving XML documents from a web service I have no control over. The XML is formatted similarly to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns:obj xmlns:ns="somenamespace">
     <address>1313 Mockingbird Lane</address>
     <residents>5</residents>
</ns:obj>
```

where the root node is in the "ns" namespace, but none of its child elements are.

After some trial and error, I found that I could deserialize the document to a C# object by doing the following:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace="somenamespace", ElementName="obj")]
public class xmlObject
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public string address { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public int residents { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
            "<ns:obj xmlns:ns=\"somenamespace\">" +
            "   <address>1313 Mockingbird Lane</address>" +
            "   <residents>5</residents>" +
            "</ns:obj>";

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(xmlObject));

        using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
             var result = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as xmlObject;

             Console.WriteLine("{0} people live at {1}", result.residents, result.address);
             // Output: "5 people live at 1313 Mockingbird lane"
        }
    }
}
```

If I omit the `XmlElementAttribute` on the individual members, I instead get an empty object. I.e. The output reads

```
0 people live at
```

(`result.address` is equal to `null`.)

I understand the rationale behind why the deserialization process works like this, but I'm wondering if there is a less verbose way to tell `XmlSerializer` that the child elements of the object are not in the same namespace as the root node.

The objects I'm working with in production have dozens of members and, for cleanliness sake, I'd like to avoid tagging all of them with `[XmlElement(Namespace = "")]` if it's easily avoidable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [`XmlRootAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx) with [`XmlTypeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.aspx) to make it so the root element, and the root element's elements, have different namespaces:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace="somenamespace", ElementName="obj")]
[XmlType(Namespace="")]
public class xmlObject
{
    public string address { get; set; }

    public int residents { get; set; }
}
```

Using the type above, if I deserialize and re-serialize your XML I get:

> ```
> <q1:obj xmlns:q1="somenamespace">
>   <address>1313 Mockingbird Lane</address>
>   <residents>5</residents>
> </q1:obj>
> ```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yOPlrI).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the contract with the web service, why not use a [DataContractSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) to deserialize the XML into the objects?